# How do I import a sync config file into my Kernel unit test?

Tags: configuration, testing

How do I import a sync config file into my Kernel unit test ?

Specifically, I have some REST resources in files
`config/sync/rest.resource.foo.yml`,`config/sync/rest.resource.bar.yml`

At present, when I run `\Drupal::service('router.builder')->rebuild()` in my `setUp()` function, it does not add in the routes for these resources, so when I make GET requests to them in the tests, I get 404.

I don't want to import all of the config for my Drupal site into the unit test, just the REST resources.

Comment: I too had a similar requirement and searched for solutions. Related discussions in Drupal Slack. https://drupal.slack.com/archives/C223PR743/p1643094724029400?thread_ts=1643094724.029400&cid=C223PR743

Comment: I am having trouble joining Drupal Slack. Would it be possible for you to summarise any of the suggestions made ?

Comment: TLDR; try `    $this->installConfig(['system', 'field', 'datetime','my_module']);` in setup method in kernel test.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two ReST resources to your module's /config/optional directory. The config files will be installed with the module if the dependencies are met.

In the kernel test, use `$this->installConfig(['your_module']);` to install the two ReST resources.